# Webscraping from a script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract the language proportion spoken at companies, using python's `BeautifulSoup`.

Yet, the information seems to come from a script, not from HTML, and I'm having some trouble.

For instance, from the following page, when I try

```
webpage ="https://www.zippia.com/amazon-com-careers-487/"
page = requests.get(webpage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

for links in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'companyEducationDegrees'}):
    raw_text = links.get_text()
    lines = raw_text.split('\n')
    print(lines)
    print('-------------------')
```

I don't get any result while the ideal result should be `Spanish 61.1%, French 9,7%, etc`

Comment: What is the result that you obtain?

Comment: ['', '{[{language.name}]} {[{language.percentage}]}%', '', '', '', '', '']
-------------------
['', '{[{degree.name}]} {[{degree.percentage}]}%', '', '', '', '', '']
-------------------

Comment: This is what I got

Comment: @hard1009 The data is loaded by Javascript, so you have to use something to emulate browser like `PhantonJS`

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out the data is put into the page via JS. However, you can still get that data, because the entire data over the comapany is always loaded with the page. You can access this data via `requests` +  `BeautifulSoup` +  `json` (+ `re`):

```
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = "https://www.zippia.com/amazon-com-careers-487/"
page = requests.get(webpage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

for script in soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'}):
    if 'getCompanyInfo' in script.text:
        match = re.search("{[^\n]*}", script.text)
        data = json.loads(match.group())
        print(data["companyDiversity"]["languages"])

        json.dump(data, open("test.json", "w"), indent=2) # Only if you want the data put in a readable format to a file (like if you want to find the path to an entry)
```